# Python regex match pattern "X<string1>:X<string2>"

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing a file which has text `"$string1:$string2"`

How do I regex match this string and extract `"string1"` and `"string2"` from it, basically regex match this pattern `: "$*:$*"`

Comment: fyi, if you are trying to get a regex to work, a page like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is very useful to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there with your own pattern, it needs three alterations in order to work as you want it.

First, the star in regexes isn't a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), as you might be expecting it from shell scripting, it's a [kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). Meaning, it needs some character group it can apply it's "zero to n times" logic on. In your case, [the  alphanumeric character class](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars) `\w`  should work. If that's too restrictive, use `.` instead, which matches any character except line breaks.

Secondly, you need to apply the regex in a way that you can easily extract the results you want. The usual way to go about it is to define [groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups), using parentheses.

Last but not least, the `$` sign is a [meta-character](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#anchors) in regexes, so if you want to match it literally, you need to write a backslash in front of it.

In working code, it'll look like this:

```
import re

s = "$string1:$string2"
r = re.compile(r"\$(\w*):\$(\w*)")

match = r.match(s)
print(match.group(1))  # print the first group that was matched
print(match.group(2))  # print the second group that was matched
```

Output:

```
string1
string2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I was going through the man pages to get a quick fix. But seeing your answer I might as well take some time to understand python regexes since I'm from C background.

Comment: Happy to help. [The python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) themselves are probably the best source in that case. They are a bit technical, but if you know the matter already they should be fine.